# Getting Bootstrap 4 navbar-brand logo to align independently of navbar-toggler button

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

I am trying to center align navbar-brand;

For mobile devices, navbar-toggler, which I have right aligned, is pushing the logo off-center.

Is it possible to have these two classes align independently of each other and, if so, how?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a href="index.php#page-top" class="navbar-brand mx-auto PElogo">
        <img src="https://www.theharbourhousehotel.co.uk/img/LOGO-HH-PNG.png" alt="Harbour House Hotel Logo" title="Harbour House Hotel">
        <h1>Harbour House Hotel</h1>
        <h2>Portpatrick</h2>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#HHnavbar" aria-controls="HHnavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="HHnavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Rooms">Rooms</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JS Fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nathonjones/va9g03tj/3/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the toggle button (or burger menu), we know that:

- the width of the burger menu is 30px
- padding of 12px on left & right each
- 1 px for the border on left/right each

So... if we add these 30px + 2*(12px) + 2*(1px) = 56px... **adding a padding left of 56px** will ensure that our brand is always in the "true" middle of the navigation...

**working snippet below**

```css
.navbar-brand img {
  width: 90px;
}

.PElogo {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 56px !important;
}

.PElogo img {
  width: 90px;
}

.PElogo h1 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin: .5rem 0 0;
}

.PElogo h2 {
  font-size: .675rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a href="index.php#page-top" class="navbar-brand mx-auto PElogo">
      <img src="https://www.theharbourhousehotel.co.uk/img/LOGO-HH-PNG.png" alt="Harbour House Hotel Logo" title="Harbour House Hotel">
      <h1>Harbour House Hotel</h1>
      <h2>Portpatrick</h2>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#HHnavbar" aria-controls="HHnavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div id="HHnavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Rooms">Rooms</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Restaurant">Restaurant</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Attractions">Attractions</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#EventsNewsOffers">News</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Location">Location</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="contact-harbour-house-hotel.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```